# VSCode, conda env with CLI parameters

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, parameters, command-line-interface, conda

When trying to debug using VSCode, I somewhat cannot set the command line parameters (CLI) for my executed Python script `main.py`. The script uses the Python package `fire` to generate the CLI parameters.

I am using VSCode remotely with the following `launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "args": ["test", "--model",  "'MODELPARAM'", "--load_model_path", "'check_points/best.pth'"],
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/home/usr/MYMODEL/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected to be able to debug with my command line parameters properly set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can `args` in launch.json help? Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args) for more details.

Comment: what are you observing (print `sys.argv`), and what do you expect to observe? Did you really mean to write `"'MODELPARAM'"` instead of `"MODELPARAM"` and `"'check_points/best.pth'"` instead of `"check_points/best.pth"`?